# How to stop/pause a worker thread, do an operation in the main thread and send the results to the worker thread in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I have a script that uses user input and based on that it generates some data (code below). The script uses threads so the GUI does not freeze while the background tasks are running.

My question is if it is possible to pause the worker thread, ask the user for some input, send it to the worker thread and then to continue the operation?

```
from tkinter.constants import LEFT, RIGHT, S
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk, time, threading, random, queue
from tkinter import NORMAL, DISABLED, filedialog

class GuiPart(object):
    def __init__(self, master, client_instance):

         canvas = tk.Canvas(master, height=600, width=1020, bg="#263D42")
         canvas.pack()

         self.button1 =  tk.Button(master, text="Mueller Matrix - MMP mode", padx=10, 
                            pady=5, bd = 10, font=12, command=client_instance.start_thread1)

         self.button1.pack(side = LEFT)


    def files(self):
         self.filena = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
                                                filetypes = (("comma separated file","*.csv"), ("all files", "*.*")))
         return self.filena

    def processing_done(self):
         tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Processing Done', 'Process Successfully Completed!')

         return


class ThreadedClient(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
    
         self.running=True
         self.gui = GuiPart(master, self)

    def start_thread1(self):
         thread1=threading.Thread(target=self.worker_thread1)
         thread1.start()

    def worker_thread1(self):
         if self.running:

              self.gui.button1.config(state=DISABLED) # can I disable the button from the main thread?
              user_input = self.gui.files() # can I pause the Worker thread here so ask the user_input from main loop?
              time.sleep(5) # to simulate a long-running process

              self.gui.processing_done()
              self.gui.button1.config(state=NORMAL)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('test_GUI')
client = ThreadedClient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I am asking this as from time to time my script ends abruptly saying that the GUI is not part of the main loop. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you considered using queues? That tends to be the convention for passing info between threads.

Comment: @JRiggles Hi, yes. I have considered it. However, I don't know/have no idea, how to trigger the queue to start the specific function in the main thread, i.e.: at the beginning to disable the button and ask for user input and at the end to display the "processing done" message.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should run the GUI from the main thread.

There is some confusion whether `tkinter` is thread-safe.  That is, if one can call `tkinter` functions and methods from any but the main thread. The documentation for Python 3 says “yes”.  Comments in the C source code for tkinter say “its complicated” depending on how tcl is built.

You should be able to call `tkinter` functions and methods from additional threads in Python 3 *if* your tkinter was built with thread support. AFAIK, the `tkinter` that comes with the downloads from python.org have threading enabled.

If you want to be able to pause additional threads, you should create a global variable, e.g. `pause = False`.
The extra threads should regularly **read** the value of this and pause their calculations when set to true, e.g.:

```
def thread():
    while run:
        while pause:
            time.sleep(0.2)
        # do stuff
```

Meanwhile the GUI running in the main thread should be the only one to **write** the value of `pause`, e.g. in a widget callback.

Some sample callbacks:

```
def start_cb():
    pause = False  # So it doesn't pause straight away.
    run = True

def stop_cb():
    pause = False
    run = False

def pause_cb():
    pause = True

def continue_cb():
    pause = False
```

If you have more complicated global data structures that can be modified be several threads, you should definitely guard access to those with a `Lock`.

**Edit1**

Threaded `tkinter` programs without classes:

- [Simple threaded tkinter example program](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/python-examples/blob/main/tkinter/tk-threaded.pyw)
- [Real-world example for unlocking ms-excel files](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/main/unlock-excel-threaded.pyw)

**Edit2:**

From the python source code for `_tkinter`:

> If Tcl is threaded, this approach won't work anymore. The Tcl
> interpreter is only valid in the thread that created it, and all Tk
> activity must happen in this thread, also. That means that the
> mainloop must be invoked in the thread that created the
> interpreter. Invoking commands from other threads is possible;
> _tkinter will queue an event for the interpreter thread, which will
> then execute the command and pass back the result. If the main
> thread is not in the mainloop, and invoking commands causes an
> exception; if the main loop is running but not processing events,
> the command invocation will block.

You can read the whole comment [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_tkinter.c).

Comment: I might advocate for the use of threading events rather than a global `pause` variable

Comment: I have the error not using tcl in the main loop every so often (I would say once in 10 tries), so that's why I have asked the original question. So how would you combine the pause method with the user input from the main thread?

Comment: @JRiggles Setting a boolean is basically an atomic operation at the Python bytecode level, so I'm not sure if an `Event` is necessary in this case. If one has multiple threads that can *all* query *and modify* shared data, then certainly I would advocate using an `Event` or `Lock`. In that case I would also say that it is a recipe for potential troubles.

Comment: @tmg-28 You have to consider that under the hood, `tkinter` is quite complicated. See "How Tk and Tkinter are Related" in the `tkinter` documentation. Furthermore in my opinion your program is being complicated by premature object-orientation. If you are only going to instantiate *one* instance, why bother with writing a class? I'll add links to some of my threaded tkinter examples without classes to my answer.

Comment: @RolandSmith That's a good point - well said!

Comment: Initially, I had a program without threads in which GUI froze, so the method outlined worked well, so GUI didn't freeze anymore.  I would be more than happy to use similar approaches that you have shown, but the error that I get is: "Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread" which I understand is related to tkinter in the worker thread (calling a function from main thread in a worker thread) - and this that may occur using your example (if I am translating my code into your example)

Comment: @tmg-28 If you search for the `Tcl_AsyncDelete` error you will see that it means that you are not running the GUI on the main thread as is required.

Comment: I know that it is related to that one, as I am calling a command from main thread in the worked thread (i.e. self.gui.files()). That's why I have asked the original question on how to pause the worker thread, run the specific command in the main thread and send the result (possibly via a queue) in the worker thread and then restart the worker thread.